# image not respecting width property in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Below is the code i made to recreate issue in a simpler manner

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            #container{
                width:500px;
                background-color:green;
            }
            table{
                width:100%;background-color:blue;
            }
            table tr td img{
                max-width:100%;
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="">
            <table style="">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="http://go-grafix.com/data/wallpapers/20/green-574309-3888x2592-hq-dsk-wallpapers.jpg"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically this works fine in chrome and other browsers

But in IE8, the `max-width` property is not obeyed. I also tried using  the `width` property still no luck

Any suggestions?

P.S:  I dont want to have it in `px`, i want to have it in `%` only

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/1zwowvht/) is the fiddle link

Comment: can u create fiddle link?

Comment: I have vague _PTSD_ memories of IE8 and using tables for layout, specifically cells (TD) - try wrapping the `img` in a `div` and applying appropriate styling to the DIV

Comment: @Arun Yeah added now thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX sure will try it

Comment: I checked your fiddle code in internet 8 browser on my machine. but image fits perfectly as it does in chrome.

P.S. The fiddle didn't run on IE8 (might be not supported there). I put your code in my dummy page and checked with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving width and height properties inline

```
<img width="100" height="100"/>
```

or

```
<img style="width:100;height:100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the responsive image. Just apply the style as follows:

```
<img src="img/xyz.jpg" class="xyz-img" width="100" height="100" />


<style> .xyz-img{width:100%; height:auto;} </style>
```